# Datasets for Classification

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, dataset, classification, multiclass-classification

does anyone some good datasets for classification via NLP?

The [BBC News Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pariza/bbc-news-summary) worked very well for me, and this is kind of what I am looking for. (classification of text documents to 3-10 labels)

Sadly, as I want to work with deep learning classification, the dataset is too small.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: You can check some datasets here: https://paperswithcode.com/datasets?task=text-classification&mod=texts&page=1

Comment: There are lots of options. Practically any tutorial you find online proposes a dataset. But you need to be more specific, there are many different kinds of classification tasks in NLP: spam detection, topic classification, author attribution, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the repo https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets to find what you want,
and also, you can search specifical dataset in https://appen.com/pre-labeled-datasets/.